# Ocotopress with github repo branch

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I'm new to both Github and Ocotopress. I've made a blog, and i have been following a tutorial from: http://schuyler.info/blog/how-to-setup-a-new-octopress-blog-on-github-pages.html

I've used `rake generate` and then `rake deploy` - which works a treat. I can see in my repo the files from _deploy. However, it says this is the master branch. And i am under the impression it shouldn't be? As the rest of the folders i added to my source folder don't show up in this site.

I can visit the website via gitpages fine. I can see my two test posts. But i updated the navigation file within the source folder and tried to push this but it doesn't seem to appear.

In the tutorial there is a bit:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "I made a post." -a
$ git push
```

This doesn't do anything for me. It says:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Even when i am sure it's not.. Can anyone save a damsel in distress?

Note - I don't see any of the commit comments on my repo, so i am figuring something has gone wrong and my master is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first switch to the `source` branch with

```
git checkout source
```

This branch will exist, as Octopress creates it for you. Then you can continue with

```
git add .
git commit -m "I made a post." -a
git push
```

Your generated files should indeed be in the `master` branch, due to the way that Github pages is set up. The `source` branch is created by Octopress so that the source that is being used to generate what is in the `master` branch is also available, in case you go to another computer, for example, and have to do a fresh clone of your repository. Without the `source` branch, you'd have to reverse engineer your own website!